# How to get keyboard Cursor global position in jetPack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, user-experience

I need to get the keyboard input cursor position in the screen at any given time  if the  Virtual keyboard is visible in jet pack compose
without being dependent on any Composable (for example when we have  list of  textfields we can't calculate the cursor Pose depending on one textfield from the list)

I didn't find anything about this topic. thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's not possible. Cursor position always depends on Focused textfield (or some other input). `InputMethodService` (or virtual keyboard) is providing only text selected range and it's up to textfield to show the cursor properly based on it's state.